# nestjs | inject a service into a module's imports

Tags: nestjs, nest

I want to use the service `ConfigService` to configure `JWTModule` when importing it

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
// <--------- here
      signOptions: { expiresIn: this.configService.get('jwt.expiresIn') },
    }),
  ],

})
export class AuthModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use the async version of that dynamic module

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({ ... })
```

as shown in the docs: https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I'll try it, then mark your answer accepted +1